# How to associate a file extension with a certain language in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Or is there a way to switch the current file's language so that the syntax is highlighted correctly?

For example, `*.jsx` is actually JavaScript but VS Code doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 793):

#### Update

Please note that JoelAZ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228725/249353) is much easier and results in the same setting changes! The answer below is still valid, just more steps & more fuss.

#### Old answer

In [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), you can add persistent file associations for language highlighting to your `settings.json` file like this:

```js
// settings.json
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
  "some_setting": custom_value,
  ...

  "files.associations": {
    "*.thor": "ruby",
    "*.jsx": "javascript",
    "Jenkinsfile*": "groovy"
  }
}
```

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or *View* -> *Command Palette* from the menu) and then type `settings JSON`. Choose **Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)** to open your `settings.json`.

To find the proper language ID, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or *View* -> *Command Palette* from the menu) and then type `Change Language Mode`. You can see the language ID in the list, e.g. type `docker` to find the language ID for Docker files (`dockerfile`). In the first entry in the example above, `.thor` is the file ending, `ruby` is the language ID.

The `Files: Associations` feature was first introduced in Visual Studio Code version 1.0 (March 2016). Check the available [wildcard patterns](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vMarch#_file-to-language-association) in the release notes and the [known language strings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers) in the documentation.

Comment: The value for the association needs to be the ID of the language/plugin, not the name. For example the VBScript plugin I installed, the ID is vbs. "*.vms" : "vbs" gets the custom extension to associate properly.

Comment: Just faced a similar issue. If adding a file association does not seem to work, make sure you don't have a `.editorconfig` file close, or align the configurations between VSCode and `.editorconfig`, the latter will take precedence

Comment: You can also put these settings in a project specific `${projectdir}/.vscode/settings.json` file.

Comment: I added .ps1 as asscociation, and enabled the ps extension, but no syntax complete, I use windows 10 and vscode 1.51.1 built 14 days ago..

Comment: ctrl + shit + p doesn't do anything for me. what is the editor menu path?

Comment: @TatiOverflow From the menu it is *View* -> *Command Palette*. (But you might wanna try the Shift button instead of the shit button, that one doesn't do much for me either.)

Comment: @MattM But to find the proper ID name you have to: Ctrl+Shift+P (or Cmd on Mac) and select "Change Language Mode" and in the list that is displayed you will the the ID of the language (ex: "dockerfile" for Docker or "bat" for Batch)

Comment: @Alex that's essential information, I did an edit suggestion to add it to the answer.

Comment: @alex and Carl, there is a much easier way using the "configure file association" menu which does not need any ID names at all.   

See the full answer with steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228725/3307796

Comment: @JoelAZ sorry for noticing your answer only now - it's a much nicer solution indeed! I've added a link to your answer to this one, I hope your answer will be upvoted to become the top answer.

Comment: No worries fren, we are all here to learn smth or to help someone.  I appreciate your update and hope this keeps on helping people.

Comment: You're a class act @Josien, linking to a better answer!

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag Honestly, I upvoted only because of mentioning a better answer. It saves a lot of time since I do not need to start parsing the answer. Instead, I jump to a better solution. Kudos to @Josien!

Comment: Despite there being a generally accepted "better" answer, this one is still useful or required in certain scenarios. For example, I needed to add `"Makefile.*": "makefile"` which cannot be done with Joel's answer.

Comment: To associates Makefile.suse and Makefile.debian to the makefile editor, use "Makefile*": "makefile" in "files.associations": { block.

Answer (score 436):

The easiest way I've found for a global association is simply to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type "change language mode") with a file of the type you're associating open.

In the first selections will be the option "Configure File Association for 'x' " (whatever file type - see image attached). Selecting this gives you the option to choose the language and will then make the filetype association permanent.

[image]

This may have changed (probably did) since the original question and accepted answer (and I don't know when it changed) but it's so much easier than the manual editing steps in the accepted and some of the other answers, and totaly avoids having to muss with IDs that may not be obvious.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me. It was not clear when manually editing the `settings.json` file what the extension ID should have been, but this method sorted it!

Comment: You're welcomed @ccbunney, glad it helps.   That was exactly the same problem I had - and I never did figure out the extension ID I needed, lol.  Anyway, I was real glad to find this solution for myself and it's cool that it's helping other ppl!  :D

Comment: Just curios, never heard of **.ps1data** as seen in your img.

Comment: @timo ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   Me neither and I never really noticed before yet there it is ... 
Perhaps a result of a typo during some earlier tweaking, idk.  Sry can't help more.

Comment: There is a significant advantage to this solution. Other solutions require you to know in advance what the language identifier is. That is OK for predefined values such as `java` as listed in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers, but we'll be at a loss for VS Code extensions installed. E.g., I installed an Apache extension for Apache `*.conf` files, and the language identifier turns out to be `apacheconf` -- how'd I guess that? I found that out by following the above solution. Then I can edit `settings.json` to further hack the mapping.

Comment: @VincentYin exactly right.  This is the easiest of the solutions for that reason and the same reason I found this solution in first place - didn't know what the lang. identifier was that I needed.  Glad ppl finding it helpful.

Comment: I tried the answer from @Josien with the most vote, for `.gpx` files to be treated as `.xml` files, but VSC doesn't syntax highlight the file still after doing that. But this solution above works well

Comment: This worked for me. Any idea how to make this work for code formatting too, not only for syntax highlighting?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting this provides the code formatting I needed.

Comment: What if language not in the list? How to add new language?

Comment: @serge I'm not sure.   Take a look at Josien's answer above (link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789145/3307796)   He does the same thing but editing config files by hand.   Maybe that let's you do what you want.

Answer (score 172):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd> on Mac), select "Change Language Mode" and there it is.

But I still can't find a way to make VS Code recognized files with specific extension as some certain language.

Comment: It appears there's a shortcut directly to `Change Language Mode`; `Alt+K, M`

Comment: `Cmd+K, M` for Mac.

Comment: This is very possible.  See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228725/3307796

Comment: Why is there a file association in VSC if it does not help?

Comment: ctrl+shit+p doesn't work for me. what is the regular non-shortcut method?

Comment: @TatiOverflow View -> Command Palette, but you better figure out why it doesn't work, at least I used the cmd palette once every 10 minutes

Answer (score 70):

eg:

```json
// .vscode/settings.json in workspace

{
  "files.associations": {
    "*Container.js": "javascriptreact",
    "**/components/*/*.js": "javascriptreact",
    "**/config/routes.js": "javascriptreact"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. This comes in handy if you have the same extension, but different language parsers based on path. E.g. you can have yml to handle Concourse pipelines in one folder and Ansible files in another.

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if I could. Been trying to persist the syntax for my Nanoc layouts and partials with an .html extension, this solved it: `"**/layouts/**/*.html": "erb"` - worth noting that the VSCode "language mode" dropdown shows the actual name of the syntax highlighter in brackets e.g. `Ruby ERB (erb)`

Comment: This works for me, however as a side issue, `equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons` doesn't properly map icons to these types.

Answer (score 24):

This works for me.

[image]

```
{
"files.associations": {"*.bitesize": "yaml"}
 }
```

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way:

1. Go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings**
2. Search "**File associations**"
3. Click on "**Add Item**"
4. Add your **extension** (*.ext) and the preferred **language**.

That's all.

[image]

Comment: Biggest problem with this method is you have to guess what the exact language string needs to be to enter into the Value column. For example, enter "HTML" and this probably won't work as expected.

Answer (score 13):

You can add the md.html extension to your `settings.json` file associations to enable markdown formatting for [markdeep](https://casual-effects.com/markdeep/) files like this:

```
    "files.associations": {
        "*.md.html": "markdown"
    },
```

The `settings.json` file lives in various locations, depending on your OS. For instance it is `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json` in macOS.
You can open and edit it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in VS Code.

Answer (score 12):

Following the steps on  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/colorizer#_common-questions worked well for me:

> To extend an existing colorizer, you would create a simple
>   package.json in a new folder under .vscode/extensions and provide the
>   extensionDependencies attribute specifying the customization you want
>   to add to. In the example below, an extension .mmd is added to the
>   markdown colorizer. Note that not only must the extensionDependency
>   name match the customization but also the language id must match the
>   language id of the colorizer you are extending.

```
{
    "name": "MyMarkdown",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "0.10.x"
    },
    "publisher": "none",
    "extensionDependencies": [
        "markdown"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [{
            "id": "markdown",
            "aliases": ["mmd"],
            "extensions": [".mmd"]
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I found solution here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/colorizer

Go to `VS_CODE_FOLDER/resources/app/extensions/` and there update `package.json`

Answer (score 11):

This, for example, will make files ending in `.variables` and `.overrides` being treated just like any other LESS file. In terms of code coloring, in terms of (auto) formatting. Define in user settings or project settings, as you like.

[image]

(Semantic UI uses these weird extensions, in case you wonder)

Answer (score 5):

I have followed a different approach to solve pretty much the same problem, in my case, I made a new extension that adds PHP syntax highlighting support for Drupal-specific files (such as .module and .inc): https://github.com/mastazi/VS-code-drupal

As you can see in the code, I created a new extension rather than modifying the existing PHP extension. Obviously I declare a dependency on the PHP extension in the Drupal extension.

The advantage of doing it this way is that if there is an update to the PHP extension, my custom support for Drupal doesn't get lost in the update process.