# Drupal 8 in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, drupal-8

I'm using Visual Studio Code for different web development. Recently I'm using Drupal 8 to develop new websites. Drupal 8 has some theme file to place some PHP code in it to changes some parts of theming. How can I debug this theme files in Visual Studio Code? I can't place any breakpoints in my code.

Comment: Found the answer in another StackOverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-make-vs-code-to-treat-other-file-extensions-as-certain-language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find yourself here in future, you might want to look at **Drupal Configuring for Visual Studio Code** available on [drupal site docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/configuring-visual-studio-code). 
The URL is: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/configuring-visual-studio-code

It explans in depth how you can configure:

- **phpcs:** provides integration for PHP CodeSniffer (phpcs) code linting.
- **Debugger for Chrome:** is a Microsoft official extension that adds JavaScript debugging support.
- **PHP DocBlocker:** provides auto-complete for PHP docblocks.
- **Empty Indent:** removes indent of empty lines on save.
- **PHP Debug:** provides launch configuration support for XDebug. Requires XDebug.
- And most important Editor Settings.

Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Drupal with vscode I suggest you to install [VS-code-drupal](https://github.com/mastazi/VS-code-drupal) extension. It makes `.module` files recognizable as php files.

If you want to debug php code I suggest you to install [vscode-php-debug](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) extension. It's a bit tricky to configure, but if you follow the guide you will succeed.

Another useful extension is [vscode-code-runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner). It runs portions of code for testing it on the fly.

Unfortunately I have not found yet a good extension for php intellisense.