# How to set html like syntax highlight for .tag (Riot.js) file and add icon for .tag file extension in vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, riot.js

How can I add the syntax highlight of a **.tag**(**RIOT.JS**) extension to use **HTML** syntax highlight mechanism and I would also like add an Icon for the .tag file extension in **VisualStudioCode**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the answer by Josien at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-make-vs-code-to-treat-other-file-extensions-as-certain-language.

Comment: I generally set by: Ctrl+Shit+P > Change Language Mode > HTML. But vscode shows syntax error for methods as they are not started with `function` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

You can either download existing icon themes from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace or you can [build your own icon theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_adding-a-new-icon-theme). The extension [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons) exposes an api which allows you to [add custom icons](https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/wiki/Customization).
I think visual studio code itself does not support adding a custom icon for a file extension by providing a path in the `settings.json` so far.