# How do you remove trailing spaces in all files except Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

In Visual Studio Code the setting

`"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true`

removes trailing white space when files are saved, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is used to format a file, but this breaks Markdown formatting.

How do you selectively turn off white space trimming for Markdown?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Add this line to your `settings.json` file.

```
"[markdown]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
}
```

Comment: How can I additionally turn it off for `text (.txt)` and `csv` files?

Comment: `ctl-k m` to bring up the language mode selector. That is the list of language specific settings you can apply. For text it looks like `[plaintext]`. [This could be helpful to set csv files to behave like plain text files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789145/25197).

Comment: Thanks! CSV does not seem to be in the list though.

Comment: Yeah.  Use the link provided in my last comment to make csv format like text.

Comment: This is a godsend ❤️

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EditorConfig` by adding `.editorconfig` at the root of your project:

```
[!markdown]
trim_trailing_whitespace: false
```

**Or** [as GollyJer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935029/how-do-you-remove-trailing-spaces-in-all-files-except-markdown/51935030#51935030), add this code snippet in the `settings.json` file:

```
"[markdown]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
}
```

Comment: that does not look like the right .editorconfig syntax.
`[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace=false`

Answer (score 2):

You can now (VSCode 1.68, May 2022) do this through the Settings GUI instead of directly your `settings.json`.

> ### [Settings editor improvements](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/04be12b63ea79aeca5e5ecabce61bf48c64492e3/release-notes/v1_68.md#settings-editor-improvements=)
>
> The Settings editor now shows a default value override indicator for language-specific settings.
>
> As a note, one can view language-specific settings by adding a language filter in the Settings editor search bar, and one can add such a filter either by typing it out explicitly, or by clicking the filter button on the right of the search bar, and selecting the "Language" option.
>
> When the default value override indicator shows up, it indicates that the default value of the language-specific setting has been overridden by an extension. The indicator also indicates which extension overrode the default value.
>
> [image: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/raw/vnext/release-notes/images/1_68/settings-editor-language-specific-default.gif]
>
> <sup>(Theme [Light Pink](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgwg.light-pink-theme))</sup>

This example above is for line wrapping, but you can adapt it to reference `trim_trailing_whitespace`.

Comment: Nice! VSCode just keeps getting better.

Answer (score 1):

Do `Ctrl-K s`. This will "Save without formatting", which also means, without trimming trailing whitespace in the file you're editing

Comment: This is really only a temporary workaround, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Add or update `.editorconfig` in root of your project and add the 2 following lines to prevent trimming on whitespace in VScode on matching file extension's

#### Update .editorconfig with following

```
[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

[*.mdx]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```