# Permanently Change Default Language for Headers to C

Tags: visual-studio-code

Bear with me if my question does not adhere to standards or sounds stupid, it is my first time asking. I am using vscode for c development. The problem is for all header files, default language used by vscode is C++ instead of C as I require. Even if I change the language to C using the panel that appears at the bottom of the editor, it still reverts to C++ after I close and restart the editor. How do i permanently make the editor recognize C?

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-make-vs-code-to-treat-other-file-extensions-as-certain-language), not sure if it works in this case though.

Comment: @tkausl. Thanks. That helped me to figure out how to do it and I managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply did not pay attention to options appearing on top of options after you click on the language in recognized at the bottom. Just clicked on "Change language associations for'.h'", set it to C and that was it.