# How to mark certain files as docker is Vscode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

The aim is to get docker syntax support in vscode. In order to achieve this, [the docker plugin was installed](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/docker), but it turns out that only Dockerfile and docker-compose are seen as docker files, but the the repository contains .docker files. Would it be possible to mark .docker files as dockerfiles in vcsode?

**Example**

In this example the someimage.docker should be marked as docker so that a docker icon would appear like the icon that is put in front of the Dockerfile. When the file is opened, there should be docker syntax support.

[image]

**Attempt to solve the issue**

The first attempt to solve the issue was [consulting the settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), but it does not seem to be possible to associated certain extensions with the docker format.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973619/45311

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically set the `files.associations` setting in the `settings.json` file.

```
{
  "files.associations": {
        "*.docker": "dockerfile"
    }
}
```

You can use the "dockerfile" [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers).

Comment: `cmd+,`, type: associations, click on edit in settings.json