# How to see variables or overrides in color for Semantic React?

Tags: less, semantic-ui-react

Are these variables or overrides files in semantic-ui -> sites-> ... ".less" files? I see them all in white and whenever I rename a file and add .less to the end, I see them in color. Should I rename them one by one? all are ".less" ? and is there a way to have autocomplete, intellisense or smth for these files also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all this files are Less, but I don't think thats a good idea to rename them all.

Instead you can change your editor configuration to treat `.variables` and `.overrides` extensions as Less files.

Here how to do it in some IDE/Editors:
 - [VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-make-vs-code-to-treat-other-file-extensions-as-certain-language)
 - [Web Storm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#register-new-association)
 - [Atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition)