# How to define a file association in a VSCode extension package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For background see [How to make VS Code to treat other file extensions as certain language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619)

That question is concerned with how to define a file association manually. This question is about how to express that in the `contributes` section of the `package.json` file for a VS Code extension.

Basically I want VS Code to treat `.mdbook` as an alias for `.json` because it's a json file with a specific schema. It's not obvious to me which contribution point is relevant or how to express this.

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward, but the documentation only hints at it.

You "contribute" the language, but only the settings you're adding or changing. To use my own application as an example, we add a file type and a friendly-name for `json` like so:

```json
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "json",
        "extensions": [
          ".mdbook"
        ],
        "aliases": [
          "Markdown Book"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Obviously the `json` language is already defined; these settings are merged.