# Theme disappeared from Jupyter

Tags: jupyter

The theme in Jupyter suddenly stop working in VSC. It is working on every other python file but not in the notebook.

None one can programme with this theme.

How do I solve this problem?

### [Click here to see the image from VSC WITHOUT theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZcuY.png)

[Click here to see the image from VSC WITH theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJYjK.png)

Answer (score 0):

VSCode doesn't understand the `.ipynb` file extension.  It believes Python files have a `.py` extension.  You can adjust the file extension assignments in `settings.json`:

[How to make VS Code treat a file extensions as a certain language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-make-vs-code-treat-a-file-extensions-as-a-certain-language)