# How to configure github.com/jinliming2/vscode-go-template to accept a custom file extension?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-templates

According to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jinliming2.vscode-go-template, this VS Code extension should support Go template language syntax highlighting for any custom file extension (see screenshot below). What I can't seem to infer from that documentation, however, is how to specify custom file extensions to which syntax highlighting should apply. Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How to make VS Code treat a file extensions as a certain language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-make-vs-code-treat-a-file-extensions-as-a-certain-language), the way to do this is to go to "file associations" in settings and add (in my case) the key-value pair `*tmpl`: `go-template`.

[image]

Now files with the `.tmpl` file extensions are highlighted as Go template language:

[image]