# How to associate a file pattern with a test file for a certain language in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing

I created a file with the name `f.spec.ts`. Visual Studio code recognizes this file as a test file:

[image]

When I rename this file to `f.e2e.ts`, Visual Studio code recognizes this file as a production file (as opposed to a test file), meaning it has the wrong tab icon and VSC explorer icon:

[image]

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio code to treat a file name of `*.e2e.ts` as a typescript test file? Or to put it another way, how do I make files that match the `*.e2e.ts` pattern use the orange TS icon?

---

#### Notes:

This question is about associating file extensions with languages, but I didn't see anything in there about my specific question: [How to associate a file extension with a certain language in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-certain-language-in-vs-code)

[This github issue for an unrelated extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17108) implies that this isn't a builtin Visual Studio Code setting, rather, it's provided by an extension? But I don't see an installed "TypeScript" extension in my editor.

That being said, in the VS Code Settings, there is a TypeScript extension. But I can't find an option there or anywhere else in the settings to define test file name patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme you're looking at is VS Code's builtin Seti [file icon theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-seti/icons/vs-seti-icon-theme.json. You can see in that file in the `fileExtensions` property's array, it has `"spec.ts": "_typescript_1",`.

- You could search for that file in your VS Code installation (a grep might help) and then edit the VS Code installation, adding a line like `"e2e.ts": "_typesript_1"` (this might cause VS Code to issue a corruption warning).
- Similarly, you could fork Seti and create your own derivative icon theme (make sure to follow [the license](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/LICENSE.txt))
- If you're not particularly attached to the Seti theme, you could look for other themes that perhaps have such distinguishing patterns built-in, or allow for customizations via settings, such as the Material Icons extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>, which has its `material-icon-theme.files.associations` setting.

---

By the way, if you're looking for the builtin TypeScript extension, you can see builtin extensions in the Extensions view if you put "`@builtin`" in the search bar. Though I'm pretty sure the TypeScript language basics and language support extensions have no relevance to this question.

The asker of the question has raised a feature request for a builtin setting to configure/customize this: [Add a "test filename pattern" setting. #197590](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197590).

Comment: Wow, I never expected the answer to be this involved and this low level. I expected this to be exposed as a setting. Thanks for the info!