# vscode resets language highlighting on select

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible

I have a few ansible task files. Vscode detects it as a yaml, and so highlights it accordingly, so I have to manually change the language from YAML to ansible every time. Which on its own is fine, but every time I unselect a file and select it again, it resets its language highlighting back to YAML.

Is there a permanent way to label a file as an ansible file so it doesn't do that? Either on the ansible side or the VsCode side

Comment: I'm out of close votes for the day. this is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973619/11107541. you'd need to write a pattern in `files.associations` to uniquely match your ansible task files. If that's not possible, you'd need to give your ansible task files a unique naming pattern to make it easier to match. Ex. `foo.ansible.yaml` instead of `foo.yaml`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to associate a file extension with a certain language in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-certain-language-in-vs-code)