# False errors in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, tera

I am writing Tera code.

```
{% extends "base" %}

{% block content %}
<main>
    <h1>{{ title }}!</h1>
    <div class="telkiniu-sarasas">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="telkinio-pavadinimas headeris">Pavadinimas</div>
            <div class="telkinio-adresas headeris">Adresas</div>
        </div>
        {% for telkinys in telkiniai %}
        <div class="row" onclick="telkinys( {{ telkinys.id }} )">
            <div class="telkinio-pavadinimas">{{ telkinys.pavadinimas }}</div>
            <div class="telkinio-adresas">{{ telkinys.adresas }}</div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock content %}
```

And I get 3 errors on line with JavaScript code

```
<div class="row" onclick="telkinys( {{ telkinys.id }} )">
```

[image]

Here are no problems on HTML only lines.
But runing code everything works as expected. Because `{{ telkinys.id }}` is replaced with a number.

```
<div class="row" onclick="telkinys( 1 )">
```

How should I remove error message from VS Code? I think VS Code interpret Tera code inside JavaScript as JavaScript code. And VS Code don't know it will be replaced with a number.

I can't think of anything to fix it.

P.S.
After searching I have found .tera is associated to HTML, So I opened Settings -> Extensions -> HTML
and searched here. Found two locations:
HTML > Format: Indent Handlebars
Format and indent `{{#foo}}` and `{{/foo}}` not selected, so I have selected it and got error about wrong index or something (But I use not Handlebars, but Tera, so it may not have effect on my code).

And second:
HTML > Format: Templating
Honor django, erb, handlebars and php templating language tags.
Selecting this one also got same error. And this also don't have Tera.

And I could not get it to work.

Comment: is there a Tera extension for vscode?

Comment: I have instaled Tera v0.0.9 by Karuna Murti

Comment: well it doesn't work :p

Comment: "*I have found .tera is associated to HTML*" - that seems to be the problem. Get rid of it to remove any syntax highlighting. If you want syntax highlighting, you need one that is capable of parsing tera templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my problem.
Tera templates are based on Jinja2, so I removed Tera extension from VS Code and added "Better Jinja" extension.
After it I associated .tera extension to jinja using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228725/3857286

Now I have good syntax highlighting and here are no problem with tera tags in javascript code.