VS Code vs. txt file: "Unable to View Diff (this is a binary file)"
I just selected a specific commit from my Git Graph list, and I'm trying to access the corresponding modifications made to a .txt file.
I get this "Unable to View Diff (this is a binary file)" message:
.
Why? How can I access these modifications in VSCode? Of course, this is not a binary file. It just contains text.
Right now I'm doing the job by using WinMerge as my git difftool, but it's much slower than just clicking on the file.
PS: Modifications made to other text files (e.g. .bat, .cpp, ...) can be easily accessed by just clicking on the file.

PPS: Modifications to any text file (.txt included!) can be accessed from the source control tab. It seems to be something related to the settings of the Git Graph extension itself.

What do you see as the currently configured file association when you trigger the "Configure file association" action for the file? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228725/11404396

@LokiRagnarok, it's "Auto detect", I think

This behavior could also be caused by file charset encoding. Prefer utf8 if possible...

Thanks, @Philippe. Unfortunately, after selecting "UTF-16 LE" on the bottom right and then "Reopen with encoding"->"UTF-8", a lot of red "NUL" symbols appear. I guess that your solution is not possible in my case, right?

@alexfrigo It looks like your file is encoded in UTF-16. It is of course wrong to attempt to open it as UTF-8. You must open it using its current encoding, and then save it as UTF-8.

@j6t it was worth trying, but it didn't solve the problem: clicked on "UTF-16 LE" on the bottom right -> saved with encoding "UTF-8" -> commit -> still "Unable to View Diff (this is a binary file)"

@alexfrigo I assume that this happens because the version you have already checked in is still UTF-16 and you are now comparing the UTF-16 version (which is considered binary) to the UTF-8 version. If you do not like this, you have to commit the converted version once (or you rewrite the commit history to fix all already committed versions).

If you want to be able to see a diff between 2 commits, the file should be committed as utf8 file in these 2 commits so you have to create at least 2 commits with utf8 encoding.

Thank you, @Philippe/@j6t! Now I can actually "Click to View Diff"! Unfortunately, I'm getting a comparison between two files made of strange Chinese (?) characters, all on the same line, instead of the two versions of my latin-characters-and-numbers text file.

Encoding is a pain: I would say that you have "saved the utf16 file as utf8" instead of "Converting utf16 file in utf8" so now the result is an utf8 file (good, that is why you are able to do a diff) but you have corrupted your content (bad ). Not all editor are good at handling encoding but notepad++ is especially good with the "convert" or "open with a specific encoding" features. I especially use this editor when having to fix character encoding (and not really trusting VSCode).
